# Using a 32bit- or 64bit specific dll depending on the process bitness

Tags: asp.net, assembly-resolution

I need to reference a DLL which is available in 2 versions (one for 32bit and one for 64bit). 
My goal is to build an web application that works on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

I thought about referencing the 32bit assembly by default and using the AssemblyResolve event to load the 64bit version (if loading the 32bit version failed):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += _AssemblyResolve;
    // Try LoadAssembly ...
}

static System.Reflection.Assembly _AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var path = string.Format(@"...\lib_x64\{0}.dll", args.Name);
    return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
}
```

But even when a BadImageFormatException occurs, the _AssemblyResolve handler will not be called. Is there any other way to achieve the proposed behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [answers for dealing with this for System.Data.SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264383/options-for-using-system-data-sqlite-in-a-32bit-and-64bit-c-sharp-world).

I think your proposed method should work but you need to move the 32-bit version so it can't be found by default, so `_AssemblyResolve` is always called for that dll. That's just a guess.

Comment: Looks like there is no better way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Most straightforward way but less flexible from my point of view is explicitly specify platform specific references in csproj file using `Condition`:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' ">
    <Reference Include="MyAssemblyx86">
```

Also you can do it dynamically using [Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx) method overload.
Parameter is of type [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) which exposes the property [AssemblyName.ProcessorArchitecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.processorarchitecture.aspx) which could be set to None, MSIL, X86, X64, IA64, AMD64

One thing you also could look into is the `Publisher Policy File` feature and command line argument `/platform:processorArchitecture`

- [Introduction to Publisher policy file](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/Publisherpolicy105062009034543AM/Publisherpolicy1.aspx)
- [How to: Create a Publisher Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Using a condition within the project file only makes a distinction at build time. Thus, it would be still required to redistribute 2 different versions.

Comment: The Assembly.Load solution would work, but this would require that I use lots of reflection. Or maybe dynamic would also be fine..

Comment: @ollifant : .NET Framework support two ways of assembly resolving - via static or dynamic reference. Dynamic referencing - Assembly.Load()/etc, static - referencing assembly through the project file or as dependency of an other reference via metadata. One thing you also could look into the `Publisher Policy File` feature and command line argument `/platform:processorArchitecture`