# OrmLite.Sqlite x86 / x64 and native library preloading

Tags: sqlite, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to target both x86 and x64 platform with a .Net 4 service and ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite

I've read about native library preloading (http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=Doc/Extra/environment.html) so it's possible to have a single project targeting both platforms.

What package(s) should I reference (via Nuget) on my project?

1. ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite32.3.9.43
2. ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64.3.9.43
3. Both?

Both packages add to my project the relative x64 and x86 SQLite.interop.dll (with copy to output folder enabled), but on a x86 machine I got the usual platform mismatch error.

Is that scenario supported by ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7392829/193634