# Is there a 64-bit SQLite.dll?

Tags: .net, sqlite, anycpu

I have SQLite in my app that I pulled using NuGet. It is version 1.0.108. Is this anyCPU or is it 32-bit? [There are many posts discussing that the DLL is bit specific.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264383/options-for-using-system-data-sqlite-in-a-32bit-and-64bit-c-sharp-world)

dumpbin says it's 32-bit DLL. But my app (set to anyCPU) runs fine in 64-bit mode calling sqlite.dll.

Is this no longer an issue and it now can be called from either mode?

NuGet: System.Data.SQLite.Core by SQLite Development Team
version: 1.0.108
Description: The official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with the ADO.NET provider.

[image]

Comment: There are many SQLite packages on NuGet.org, so please be specific on which one (and its version) you are using.

Comment: @LexLi - added to the question. Please let me know if you need more info. thanks - dave

Comment: It is very bad that those guys don't use a service like GitHub to host the code publicly for easy navigation, but if I remember correctly, their code base changed significantly in the past. Initially they had two assemblies for x86/x64 (C++/CLI), which is why many old threads said that you must use the proper one, and then after a while they figured out a way to use a single assembly for both (to load native dependencies automatically). As you are using the latest, what you observed can be expected.

Comment: BTW, if I were you I might use Microsoft's implementation, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/